# Is there a way to limit rows in the right table of a left join to only be used once?

Tags: sql, mysql-5.6

I am trying to identify where there was some data loss by comparing two sets of data.

The first set of data contains a truncated non-unique barcode, and a timestamp to the second, which I've found is also not unique.  This is stored in a table called `restoredData`, as this table was created from text backups created every night.

The second set is really two tables, one called `items` and `itemss_archive`.  They too have non-unique short barcodes and non-unique timestamps.

`restoredData` has 2,437,910 records, one per `item`.  `items` has 405,009 and `items_archive` has 1,589,768, for a total of 1,994,777 rows.  So there's at least 443,113 more records in `restoredData` than there is is in the union of `items` and `items_archive`.

However, whenever I try to `LEFT JOIN` `restoredData` to the union of `items` and `items_archive`, I get 2,437,910 matches, searching for where the `LEFT JOIN` is null ie where there is no matching record in items + items_archive, I get a count of 0.  I've tried joining on barcode, timestamp, and both at the same time with the same results.

This is definitely due to the non-uniqueness I have on all my avaiable keys.  But if I was able to only allow a row from my `(SELECT t_stamp, barcode FROM items UNION ALL SELECT t_stamp, barcode FROM items_archive) as allItems` to only be used ONCE for the join, ie so that it cannot match with multiple things in `restoredData`, I think it would give me the information I am actually looking for, records that were recorded via text but got lost from the items and items_archive tables.

Is there way to do that in SQL?  Or am I going to have to do this programatically with say python, go row by row through `restoredData`, find a match, and if there is a match delete it so it can't be used again?

Another thing, I know this can't be correctly matching because in my items and items_archive tables, I have a special barcode "NO_READ" which happened during errors reading the barcode, but no such value is found in the entirety of `restoredData`.

I am using MySQL 5.6.

For reference

```
restoredData table, 2,437,910 records
barCode (Varchar(13), non-unique), t_stamp (Datetime, non-unique)

items and items_archive table 1,994,777 records total
barCode (Varchar(13), non-unique), t_stamp (Datetime, non-unique)
```

To give an example, I could have barcode1, timestamp1 appear 4 times in my `restoredData` and only once in my `items`+`items_archive` table, and the result as it stands is this

```
 restoredData                 items+items_archive
 barcodeCol  t_stampCol       barcode2Col  t_stamp2Col
 barcode1    timestamp1       barcode1     timestamp1             
 barcode1    timestamp1       barcode1     timestamp1             
 barcode1    timestamp1       barcode1     timestamp1             
 barcode1    timestamp1       barcode1     timestamp1
```

What I want is this

```
 restoredData                 items+items_archive
 barcodeCol  t_stampCol       barcode2Col  t_stamp2Col
 barcode1    timestamp1       barcode1     timestamp1             
 barcode1    timestamp1       NULL         NULL             
 barcode1    timestamp1       NULL         NULL             
 barcode1    timestamp1       NULL         NULL
```

Comment: Not sure I've fully understood your problem, but can you not `SELECT * FROM restoredData r WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM items i where i.barCode=r.barCode AND i.t_stamp = r.t_stamp )` ?

Comment: The problem to be more clear is that I could have 10 rows of the same barcode and timestamp in my `restoredData` but only 4 rows of the same barcode and timestamp in my `items`+`items_archive`, however doing a left join will match every single one of those 10 rows.  Instead, I'd rather only 4 get matched and the other 6 get a `NULL`.

Comment: hmm unless there is some other data columns that distinguishes the `6` from the `4` that you need to identify I think you'll need to do a row by row comparison, this can probably be done with iterators, but I'm not all that familiar so will leave for someone else to attempt an answer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to create some temporary tables with indexes and then use the index to create a ranking so that you can use that to create a unique column between the two datasets:-

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE items_full (t_stamp datetime, barcode varchar(13), idx int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT)

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE restored_data (t_stamp datetime, barcode varchar(13), idx int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT)

Insert into items_full
SELECT t_stamp, barcode FROM items 
UNION ALL 
SELECT t_stamp, barcode FROM items_archive

Insert into restored_data
SELECT t_stamp, barcode FROM restoreddata


Select t_stamp, barcode, DENSE_RANK() OVER (Partition By barcode, t_stamp order by idx) as myrank from items_full bb

left join 

(select t_stamp, barcode, DENSE_RANK() OVER (Partition By barcode, t_stamp order by idx) as myrank from restored_data) aa 

on bb.t_stamp=aa.t_stamp and bb.barcode=aa.barcode and bb.myrank=aa.myrank

where aa.t_stamp is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with counting. Where the count per barcode and timestamp does not match, you'll have to inspect the related records.

```
select
  r.barcode,
  r.t_stamp,
  r.cnt as recover_count,
  i.cnt as itemtables_count
from
(
  select barcode, t_stamp, count(*) as cnt
  from restoreddata
  group by barcode, t_stamp
) r
left join
(
  select barcode, t_stamp, count(*) as cnt
  from
  (
    select barcode, t_stamp from items
    union all
    select barcode, t_stamp from items_archive
  ) both
  group by barcode, t_stamp
) i on  i.barcode = r.barcode 
    and i.t_stamp = r.t_stamp
    and i.cnt <> r.cnt;
```

Comment: Yea I did some counts before and it is a LOT of records.  There's 16,000 instances alone where the two or more items of the same barcode got scanned in the same second.  So I've decided to go programatically.  Thanks for the answer though.